# How would the focal length of a convex lens change if it is submerged in a liquid of higher optical density?

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction, lenses

We know that when a convex glass lens is submerged under water, it's focal length increases- As refractive index of the pair of media reduces and the light rays deviate less to meet the principal axis at a farther point. Furthermore, if the lens is submerged under a liquid of same optical density, the light rays don't bend and the focal point lies at infinity.

I wonder how would the focal length change if the very bounding liquid is denser than lens.Considering a lens as a set of prisms how will the light rays actually refract from the surfaces??
[image: Considering a lens as a set of prisms how will the light rays actually refract from the surfaces??]

Any help or corrections would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can see this from the Lensmaker's equation for thin lenses
$$\frac{1}{f} = \frac{n'-n}{n} \left( \frac{1}{R_1} - \frac{1}{R_2} \right)$$
$R_1,R_2$ are the curvature radii of the surfaces of the lens. $n^\prime$ is the refractive index of the interior of the lens, whereas $n$ is the refractive index of the medium outside the lens.

So for $n\approx 1$ (lens in air) you get
$$\frac{1}{f_{Air}} = (n'-1) \left( \frac{1}{R_1} - \frac{1}{R_2} \right)$$

Hence,
$$\frac{f}{f_{Air}}=\frac{(n'-1)n}{n'-n}$$

For thick lenses it gets a little more complicated, I mean in a tiresome way.

If the liquid medium outside is more optically dense ($n>n^\prime$), the lens in liquid will have negative focal length if it would be positive otherwise. This means a converging lens turns into a diverging one and vice-versa.

Comment: The convergent lens becomes divergent. It is still convex, the shape does not change when you deep it in a liquid.

Comment: @nasu: sorry, I noticed it immediately after writing. ;-) Corrected.

Comment: Thank you very much for the exposition but I fail to comprehend the maths used here; This is the first time I found out about Lens maker's equation and don't know about it's derivation. Nonetheless I got to know that Focal length drops to negative.
thank you.

Comment: @VaishnavChandra: I'm afraid if you don't understand the math in my answer, a detailed derivation would help you even less. The focal length drops to negative for n>n' because in the formula for f, if you subtract a bigger number (n) from a smaller number (n'), you get a negative number.

Comment: @VaishnavChandra before the lens equation it's easier to look at snell's law. Basically the higher the difference between the refractive indexes the higher the bend.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law